# "A componentless route cannot have a named outlet set"

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my ng2 app, I have the following route:

```
const modalRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: 'modal_1',
    component: SomeModalComponent,
    outlet: 'modal',
    children: [
        {
            path: 'step_one',
            component: OneSubmodalComponent,
            outlet: 'submodal'
        },
        {
            path: 'step_two',
            component: AnotherSubmodalComponent,
            outlet: 'submodal'
        },
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'step_one',
            outlet: 'submodal',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        }
    ]
}];
```

I have an un-named router outlet for main page content, and this route describes the routing for one modal, which is routed to a named outlet `modal` and itself contains a named outlet `submodal`.

As of Angular 2.2.4, this had worked fine, but upon updating to 2.3.0+, I now get the error `Invalid configuration of route 'modal_1/': a componentless route cannot have a named outlet set`. I can see that this is because the redirect route does not have a component defined, but it *should* just redirect to `step_one` which has that defined. Is there something off about the design of my routing here?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue-- with the above route, I would get paths like
`/main(modal:modal_1/(submodal:step_1))`, which seems to not work properly now. Simplifying the path to `/main(modal:modal_1/step_1)` now lets it work properly. My route then becomes:

```
const modalRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: 'modal_1',
    component: SomeModalComponent,
    outlet: 'modal',
    children: [
        {
            path: 'step_one',
            component: OneSubmodalComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'step_two',
            component: AnotherSubmodalComponent
        },
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'step_one',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        }
    ]
}];
```

Comment: Are those components lazy loaded though?